# A phrase (or idiom) to show that something holds no value to you

Tags: idiom-requests, phrase-requests

I'm currently translating a novel on my own, and I came across a sentence that seems rather strange in English if I were to translate it word for word. A man says that something is "as important to me as a 'clipped nail'."

I understand the character is downplaying the significance of the thing, however... Is there a better phrase (or maybe an idiom) that I can replace it with for English readers to understand that this character is saying "something" is worthless, without using the exact words?

Thanks for your time.

EDIT:

Something similar could be like "swatting flies" or "lions don't listen to the opinions of sheep". Those are close in meaning, however, I need something fitting for a conversation about discarding something because it's insignificant/worthless to the speaker.

Comment: Please provide a sentence where this phrase or expression is needed. You can add _______ where the expression is required.

Comment: @Sumanta - That doesn't mean that something is worthless, it means that the person is able to shrug off difficulties without being unduly troubled by them.

Comment: @Sumanta "Like water off a duck's back" would be good, but in this instance, the character is referring to this "thing" as being useless to him.

Comment: @Mari-LouA The closest meaning I can compare it to is that this man looks down on this thing as insignificant. I'm sorry I can't think of more to explain it. It's a head-scratcher for me, too.

Comment: ["Don't give a X about"](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/465038/191178)?

Comment: @Laurel I was tempted to go with a more casual expression like that. However, this character, in particular, is very intelligent and speaks very eloquently. So curse words are out of character for him. But the thought is funny.

Comment: @Conrado That's actually really good. I may re-word that to fit. Thank you, sir!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Phrase equivalent to "I don't give a damn", not out of place in a 1930s context](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/465031/phrase-equivalent-to-i-dont-give-a-damn-not-out-of-place-in-a-1930s-context) Laurel there gives a lot of synonyms, including some that would only be used by the educated ('don't care a (brass) farthing'; 'don't care a whit' ...).

Comment: That's perfect, @EdwinAshworth! That matches this character perfectly and captures the meaning! Thank you!!

Comment: You'll find some comparisons in the dictionary: [rat's ass](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/rat's%20ass) "*vulgar*--a minimum amount or degree of care or interest : HOOT, DAMN —usually used in the phrase *don't give a rat's ass*" m-w

Comment: I'd change as little as needed, not as much as I can: Important to me as a **hangnail**.

Comment: “as important as a nail clipping” for minimal change. Hangnails are annoying.